# collapsing nav bar at X browser width @media query not working

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Hi guys just wondering why I cant get my media query to shrink my nav bar. I have the following css:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width:1024px)
{
  div.large-7.push-5.columns.last{
  height: emCalc(1px);
}
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 745px){
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
    color: $steel;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px $steel, 0 16px 0 1px $steel, 0 22px 0 1px $steel;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

Everything works as intended on mobile, but in the desktop/laptop browser window it won't respond like I want when i shrink the browser around the 745px mark. I don't know why and haven't been able to find any help on the issue. If you would prefer to see the site in action it's www.omegadesignla.com . Thanks in advance for the awesome inputs and upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Media queries should normally use min-width and max-width not min-device-width and max-device-width, the latter two being fixed by the device regardless of window size.

Comment: i tried taking out 'device' but it made no difference

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS rules to this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:1024px)
{
  div.large-7.push-5.columns.last{
  height: emCalc(1px);
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 745px){
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a {
    color: $steel;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 33px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}
  .top-bar .toggle-topbar.menu-icon a:after {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px $steel, 0 16px 0 1px $steel, 0 22px 0 1px $steel;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    top: 0;
    width: 16px;
}
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
```

Comment: did you just remove the 'device'? i did that it didnt make a difference.

Comment: This works.  I just tried it on something else . . .

Comment: ok, but why doesnt it work on my site? can you look on my site and see?

Comment: When it gets to a certain size, it drops the links in the nav bar down and shirnks the container

Comment: Here sure is!  What exactly do you want the navbar to do at a certain screen size?  Please make a JSFiddle if you know how.

Comment: do you see how the nav bar messes things up when your are shrinking the browser size? I would just like it to become a menu icon with the links instead of messing the layout up

Comment: Do you have a JSFiddle that I can mess with?

Comment: no i don't have one i made an account but im using foundation framework so i dont think it will look right.

Comment: Yes, please try it.  jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Try to create your problem there.

Comment: i tried but fiddle wont load foundation so how can i create it?